# .htaccess: redirect to show a landing page instead of main site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to put up a .html landing page in a site.  What I want is when users go to `www.mydomain.com`, they'll be redirected to the html landing page (I have named it `index.html`). Then the can click on a link directing to `index.php`to view the main site at `www.mydomain.com/index.php`.

Been trying to play around with the `.htaccess` with no success so far (maybe my rewrite rules are wrong). Here's the content of the `.htaccess` file:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .htm .html .php 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.htm [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want people to land on index.html by default and not index.php, then setting the DirectoryIndex would do the job. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

You wouldn't even need rewrites in this case.

Comment: the issue with that is that it'll keep on redirecting to index.html even if i put an index.php on the url.
what i want is when you go to www.mydomain.com/index.html, you'll get to the landing page. when you go to www.mydomain.com/index.php, you'll get to the main site.

Comment: I don't believe that should happen. If you do www.mydomain.com/ it'll show index.html without redirecting, if you go to /index.html, that'll work just fine. And if you link to /index.php, that'll work fine too. The DirectoryIndex just sets what you see when you go to / on its own.